# How do I format this Date object for a Windows Form App in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I am making a simple Windows Forms App that allows the user to select any file and rename it to a default formatted name, based on what they entered in the text fields.

Example: "08_21_2015_DrJohnSmith_HowToSellHomes.mp3" --  http://postimg.org/image/ds52o0xu1/

The problem I am having is I don't know how to format the date text box so it saves the file in this format:

"08_21_2015_DrJohnSmith_HowToSellHomes.mp3"

Right now its saving the file in this format:

"Friday, August 21, 2015DrJohnSmith_HowToSellHomes.mp3"

I know this is very easy to do, but I am new to programming, and just started learning C# this week, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code. The link above of a image of the form.

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void selectFileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            }

            private void outputFileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var outputFolder = outputFileTB;
                folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
                outputFolder.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            }

            private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
            {
                selectFileTB.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }

            private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                File.Move(selectFileTB.Text, outputFileTB.Text + "/" + dateTimePicker1.Text + speakerTitleTB.Text + firstNameTB.Text + 
                    lastNameTB.Text + "_" + messageTitleTB.Text + ".txt");     
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not forget to accept one of the answers that solved your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you're using `dateTimePicker1.Text` - which returns the textual representation of the selected date value *as it appears to the user*, this is obviously not what you want :)

First, extract the actual `DateTime` value by using `dateTimePicker1.Value` instead of `.Text`, then use the `DateTime.ToString()` method and specify a format string to have complete control over what is generated, like so:

```
dateTime.ToString( "MM_dd_yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
```

When using `.ToString` (on dates, numbers, or most values really), if it has an overload that accepts an `IFormatInfo` use it to explicitly specify either `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` (as per current Microsoft FxCop guidelines). If you want consistent behaviour across multiple platforms be sure to use `InvariantCulture` because if you use `CurrentCulture` then the output text might not be what you expect - this isn't a problem with completely custom strings like `"MM_dd_yyyy"` but if you use standard format strings like `"g"` or `"d"` then you'll see wildly different results on different machines.

BTW, I strongly recommend you use `yyyy-MM-dd` as a date format instead of `MM_dd_yyyy` this is so that files can be sorted chronologically in a text list (such as in Windows' File Explorer), otherwise you'll have files sorted by month, then day, then by year, which makes no sense.

Finally, note that in format strings `MM` is for Months but `mm` is for Minutes.

Here's a reference:

- Standard format strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx
- Custom format strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks you so much Dai, it worked like a charm! Per your suggestion I changed it to `yyyy-MM-dd`, thanks for that, because that's one of the main reason for this app to make sure the files are automatically sorted chronologically in the folder. Soon as I reach 15points I will come back and up vote Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
dateTimePicker1.Text
```

with

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Wow! That made so much sense! Thanks It worked like a charm. Soon as I reach 15points I will come back and up vote Thanks you very much!